# Unable to get like status with facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-tabs

I have a Facebook tab application in which page should be redirected to other page only when user like. In previous version 3.2.3 SDK provides the status straight a way... But it was deprecated after November 2014.

My current server version is 5.3 but SDK4.4.0 supports only on PHP 5.4 or higher. But I can't upgrade my server due to some other reason.

So can anyone assist me to get like status on Facebook SDK, which can support in PHP 5.3?

Answer (score 1):

You could still use the deprecated (but working) [facebookarchive/facebook-php-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37097880/165071) with PHP 5.3 and fetch the [/object/likes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/object/likes) using it.

Comment: Thanks for follow up

Answer (score 0):

Later I understand that the like status has been deprecated since november 2014, we have another SDK 4.4.0 which provides easier options.

Thanks